# Почему не ставится фокус в конец текста?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

а ставится в начало инпута

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('input').focus();
})
```

```html
<input type="text" value="texttext text">
<button class="edit">поставить фокус в конец текста</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А почему Вы решили, что он должен туда ставиться?

Comment: @Igor, так хотят просто. та и  вроде логично . или нет?

Comment: нет, не логично. Иначе бы при навигации по элементам страницы с клавиатуры так бы сделали изначально. Но, как мы видим, при получении инпутом фокуса без помощи мыши, его содержимое выбирается целиком - разработчики это не просто так сделали.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  let inpValue = $('input').val();
  $('input').focus().val('').val(inpValue);;
})
```

```html
<input type="text" value="texttext text">
<button class="edit">поставить фокус в конец текста</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```